# How to get values from JSON strings using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

What do i do to get the value's of `code` in both badgeIndex:1 & 2?

```
"selectedBadges":
[
  {
    "badgeIndex":1,
    "code":"CP005",
    "name":"Chapter 2"
  },
  {
    "badgeIndex":2,
    "code":"FR092",
    "name":""
  }
]
```

Comment: First step is to read the documentation...

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: Google deserialize json.

Comment: @Gnqz i wouldn't ask it here if I didn't googled it first, i already know how to deserialize but not this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this website](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate c# classes from your json.

```
public class SelectedBadge
{
    public int badgeIndex { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<SelectedBadge> selectedBadges { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use:
`RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

Then you can get each element for example:
`String s = ro.selectedBadges[0].code;`

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, now if i want to show the name, do i just use `ro.selectedBadges[0].name`?

Comment: @RemivanBuuren yes, selectedBadges[0] is the first element of the list, and it is a SelectedBadge class with 3 properties badgeIndex, code and name. If you can get (or set) a property you need to use the "." operator.